# How to Count records in query with association table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three `tables`

```
PackingLists
ItemsToPackingLists
Items
```

I would like to have a list of all PackingLists with the Number of items per PackingList and the WeightInGramms for the PackingList.

I wrote the following query, but it gives wrong results. I guess I have to arrange the `joins` somehow different.

Any help how to refactor the query is appreciated.

```
SELECT  p.ID,
        p.NameOfPackingList,
        COUNT(ItemsToP.ItemID) AS NumberOfDifferentItems,
        SUM(items.WeightInGrams * ItemsToP.Quantity) AS WeightInGramms

FROM PackingLists AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemsToPackingLists AS ItemsToP 
    ON  (ItemsToP.PackingListID = p.ID)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Items AS items 
    ON  (ItemsToP.ItemID = items.ID)
GROUP BY p.ID,p.NameOfPackingList
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide examples of the incorrect results you are getting (both sample data and the results).  The query looks correct.

Comment: If you're looking for the number of **different** items then you'll need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT ItemsToP.ItemID)`

Comment: @TomH . . . Although possible, that seems unlikely given that `ItemsToPackingLists` has a `Quantity` column.

Comment: ItemsToPackingLists has a Quantity Column, indeed.

Comment: I hope tomorrow I will find some time to extend the text with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear what you want to get, but two options to check.

1. Use  COUNT(Distinct ItemsToP.ItemID) instead of  COUNT(ItemsToP.ItemID), you might including the same item twice in one package (with different quantities), and naming of the col 'NumberOfDifferentItems' suggest using distinct as well.
2. However, your question is 'Number of items per PackingList'. To my understanding you should sum the quantities, SUM(ItemsToP.Quantity) instead of counting the IDs.